# how to give permission to intel realsense camera on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, realsense

OS:Ubuntu 18.04
camera: Intel realsense D415

I can use cheese to show the compound image of the camera. But when I run

```
import pyrealsense2 as rs
pipeline = rs.pipeline()
pipeline.start()
```

It throws out error `access failed for 8086:ad6 uid: 1-1-12`
Is anyone that knows how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install Intel Realsense permission scripts located in librealsense source directory.

For that, first, git clone the librealsense to a local folder

```
git clone https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense
```

Next, run the following commands to copy the `99-realsense-libusb.rules` files to the `rules.d` folder

```
sudo cp config/99-realsense-libusb.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/
```

And, then `udevadm control` to modify the internal state of the running udev dameon to reload rules. Also, `udevadm trigger` to request device events from the kernel.

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo udevadm trigger
```

**Update**: I recently faced the `Runtime error: backend-v412.cpp:988 - Frames didn't arrived within 5 seconds`. Seems like the pipeline is not able to handle the framebuffers, and there is quite a lot of drop in the frames, specifically above 720p, 15 frames/sec.

[image]

Any resolutions?

**Update 2:**

Resolution: As suspected it is a pipelining issue w.r.t the amount of the data the USB port can carry. To prevent frame drop or overload of data through the USB, it has to be connected to a Motherboard that has USB 3.1 Gen 1 specifications. Refer to page 78 of this document https://www.intelrealsense.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Intel-RealSense-D400-Series-Datasheet-June-2020.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! But it appeared another issue `RuntimeError: Frame didn't arrive within 5000`. the camera shows the image but a while after the error appeared. Any ideas about the issues? Thank you very much!

Comment: Followup Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63027477/2478346

Comment: Yes, I just found that if I used the computer in the lab the problem never appears. You can check if the the usb port in you pc is usb3.0

Comment: Yeah, it is a pipelining issue w.r.t the amount of the data the USB port can carry. To prevent frame drop or overload of data through the USB, it has to be connected to a Motherboard that has USB 3.1 Gen 1 specifications.
Refer to page 78 of this document 
https://www.intelrealsense.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/Intel-RealSense-D400-Series-Datasheet-June-2020.pdf